# MVC html helpers change hiddenfor attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have am using html helper fields below, my issue I need the make these hiddenfor elements not hidden when checkbox is checked.

```
@Html.HorizontalFormFieldFor(model => model.InsaatHizmetBedeli)
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tadilatMi, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @if (!Model.tadilatMi.HasValue)
        {
            Model.tadilatMi = false;
        }
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.tadilatMi.Value, new { @Name="tadilatmi" });
    </div>
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.myHiddenProperty)
```

here is my jquery code:

```
$("input[name='tadilatmi']").on("change", function () {    
    if ($("input[name='tadilatmi']").is(":checked")) {
      $("#myHiddenProperty").show()
    } 
})
```

of course it not works.. how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generating an input with `type="hidden"` which is always hidden. The `jQuery.show()` method is for toggling the display of elements styled with `display:none;` and its changes it to `display:block;`

You could do this by changing the `type` attribute

```
if ($("input[name='tadilatmi']").is(":checked")) {
  $("#myHiddenProperty").attr('type', 'text')
}
```

or by making the input `type="text"` and styling it as hidden

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myHiddenProperty)
```

with the following css

```
#myHiddenProperty {
    display: none;
}
```

and then your original script will work.

I suspect however that you want to toggle the visibility back if the checkbox is then unchecked, in which case you should have an `else` block

```
if ($("input[name='tadilatmi']").is(":checked")) {
  $("#myHiddenProperty").show()
} else {
    $("#myHiddenProperty").hide()
}
```

Side note: your using an awful hack in order to make you checkbox bind to a `nullable bool` property (by chaninging the `name` attribute) and your `label` does not even work as a `label` (clicking on it will not toggle the `checkbox`). I recommend you use a view model with

```
 public bool Tadilatmi { get; set; }
```

and in the view simply use

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tadilatmi , new { @class = "control-label" })
<div class="controls">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tadilatmi);
</div>
```

and change the script to (which is more efficient)

```
var hiddenElement = $('#myHiddenProperty');
$('#tadilatmi').change(function () {    
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      hiddenElement.show()
    } else {
      hiddenElement.hide()
    }
})
```

Your `myHiddenProperty` property could then include a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue("Tadilatmi")]` or similar conditional validation attribute.